# Can't open .jar file. JNI error. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/exec/ExecuteStreamHandler

Tags: java, linux, jar, manjaro

just trying to run a .jar file and get this message:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/exec/ExecuteStreamHandler
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteStreamHandler
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 7 more
```

Doing some searching I was able to find some info on perhaps an issue with commons-logging but I've no clue where to go from there or if that's even correct.

Was able to run older versions just fine but something must've changed & I can't contact the creator.. Any help out there? I'm running Manjaro Linux..

Comment: Can you link the jar file?

Comment: Thanks I figured it out. Used a program called One-jar to embed jar files.

Comment: Then answer your own question and accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the exception it is clear that you are missing org/apache/commons/exec/ExecuteStreamHandler.class in your classpath. Add commons-exec.jar in your classpath.

Comment: Right but where would that be? This isn't my project. It's just a .jar file I'm trying to use..

Comment: How are you running it? If from command line with java  -jar then specify everything (including your jar) on the commandline using -cp: 
java -cp MyJar.jar:lib/* com.somepackage.subpackage.Main

Comment: Thanks I figured it out. Used a program called One-jar to embed jar files.